# EF not creating database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've created this project

[image]

In data I've installed `EF`. `WebApi` is my startup project and it has refference to Business which has reference to Data.

In data I have this:

```
namespace NewsWebsite.Data
{
    public class NewsWebsiteContext : DbContext
    {
        public NewsWebsiteContext():base("name=NewsWebsiteContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<NewsWebsiteContext>(null);
        }
        public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PostLocale> PostLocales { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

And in data's app.config I have:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NewsWebsiteDbContext" connectionString="Server=.\compname;initial catalog=NewsDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="Syste.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And I have exact same in webapi's web.config (server name is correct).

When I run application it is not creating database. Why?

---

If someone will face that problem I had 2 mistake:

1) I had base("name=NewsWebsiteContext") instead of `NewsWebsiteDbContext`

2) I had `providerName="Syste.Data.SqlClient"` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`

and I was not using migrations. Just do

`enable-migrations -EnableAutomaticMigration:$true` and then `update-database` that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When use

```
Database.SetInitializer<NewsWebsiteContext>(null);
```

EF not create automatic database.
Try add migration and update database